apparmor aa-logprof and aa-genprof both seems broken
I'm trying to write an apparmor profile based on this tutorial to manually fix some broken electron apps after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, but I can't get aa-logprof or aa-genprof to work.
sudo aa-logprof 
Updating AppArmor profiles in /etc/apparmor.d.                    

ERROR: Can't parse mount rule mount options in (rw,bind) options in (rw,rbind) -> /storage**,

I'm getting the same error for aa-genprof.
This is the current version of apparmor-utils:
Package: apparmor-utils
Version: 4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1

Is there something broken on my end or is this a known bug? Was not able to spot any open issue for apparmor-utils.

Okay, work around is to remove all profiles, which contain the /storage** line in /etc/apparmor.d/. I had an adbd and android_app profile, which seems to be invalid.

When I look at (working) profiles on my 24.04 system, mount options appear to be space-separated options=(rw rbind) even though the apparmor.d manpage shows them comma-separated. I wonder if that is significant?
